# Can't find a workaround for "Column is invalid in the select list"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a database with some tables containing data on different managers and their companies and seniors. The two tables in question look like this:

Company:

```
company_code  founder
C1            Monika
C2            Samantha
```

Lead_Manager:

```
lead_manager_code   company_code
LM1                 C1
LM2                 C2
```

I need to return the company_code, founder and the total number of lead managers. I have this code:

```
SELECT c.company_code, COUNT(lm.lead_manager_code) as lead_managers
FROM Lead_Manager lm
INNER JOIN Company c ON lm.company_code = c.company_code
GROUP BY c.company_code;
```

It returns the company_code and total lead managers but no founder. When I try this code:

```
SELECT c.company_code, c.founder, COUNT(lm.lead_manager_code) as lead_managers 
FROM Lead_Manager lm
INNER JOIN Company c ON lm.company_code = c.company_code
GROUP BY c.company_code;
```

it throws "Column 'Company.founder' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." I've read up on the cause and I understand it, but I can't find a workaround.

Comment: I am curious about what part of the error message you don't understand.  It seems really clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include ALL the columns that aren't in aggregate functions in your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.company_code, c.founder, COUNT(lm.lead_manager_code) as lead_managers 
FROM Lead_Manager lm
INNER JOIN Company c ON lm.company_code = c.company_code
GROUP BY c.company_code, c.founder;
```

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work. I tried it now and suddenly it does.

Comment: Not sure what "didn't work", means @IsaacOpperman but I assume you'd not quite got the syntax right. Glad this works for you though.